# I want to invalidate all [self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am adding

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];
```

but if user restart the song then the this selector should not get performed. So I just want to 
know how I can cancel that.  Because after 20 second it will get invoked but I don't want that, and reschedule

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];
```

I'v so many

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showLyrics) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

I want to cancel all those, which I've scheduled before.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelector:@selector(showLyrics) 
                                           target:self
                                         argument:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSTimer` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

`NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(showLyrics) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

To cancel:

`[timer invalidate];`

But you may want to invalidate before you start each time or keep timers in an array and iterate through them to cancel all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSTimer` and save a reference to it instead of `performSelector`.  <strike>Afaik `performSelector` can't be cancelled.</strike>  **Edit:** Apparently it *can* be cancelled, see omz's answer...

```
self.showLyricsTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(showLyrics)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:NO];
```

To cancel the timer you use:

```
[self.showLyricsTimer invalidate];
```

But be careful to also invalidate the timer when your view disappears f.e. in the `viewWillDisappear` callback, since `NSTimer` retains it's target.

Answer (score 0):

> Cancels perform requests previously registered with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

`+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument`

It seems this is what you are looking for or what you were looking for~~